# Emma code coverage not generated when uncaught exceptions are thrown

Tags: android, code-coverage, emma, build.xml

Emma code coverage is not generated when an uncaught exception is thrown in the Android Activity under test. The coverage, however, is generated successfully if the test passed! I am using SDK r15, Emma 1.6.x macosx and the default build.xml. The following is the output of the `ant test` target:

```
[exec] com.stackoverflow.android.test.ActivityTest:INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=java.lang.ArithmeticException
[exec] INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
[exec] INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
[echo] Downloading coverage file into project directory...
[exec] remote object '/data/data/com.stackoverflow.android/coverage.ec' does not exist
```

Is this normal? I am new to Emma, but I know JaCoCo sometimes does that! Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I have just ran into this issue not involving android sdk or mac os.  I'm on windows covering a standard JDK codebase with JUnit Tests. I am new to Emma as well but here is what I've found to prove that it is normal.  :(  The following link is from EclEmma's own FAQ.

[Why are JUnit4 test cases with expected exceptions shown as not covered?](http://www.eclemma.org/faq.html#trouble05)

So if anyone knows of a way around this, I would love to hear it.